# jquery sortable plugin with "sliding effect"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

jQueryUI has got a nice plugin, Sortable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
I'm very pleased with that plugin but I'm only missing one thing. And that is instead of let the elements that changes position pop/jump to its new position, I'd like them to "slide" to that new position instead. By other words, make it a bit more smoother.

I've searched the 'net for three days now and havn't found one plugin that does that (!?!??). I mean come on, there must be one, right?

I've also tried to modify the code a bit on my own, and I got it to work sort of (by cloning the element, slide the clone to the new position, then delete the clone. meanwhile I'm hiding the original element and unhide it after deleting the clone). But it doesn't work very well, and I thought there must be a better one out there somewhere!

So I'm really begging for help. Either modifying help, or if you've seen a plugin that does this, please (:

Comment: I noticed now why my method "doesnt work". It seems like if I'm dragging my element too fast, the jquery-ui script fails to notice I even dragged it, lol. I even downloaded a fresh new copy (just to be sure) and tried to drag it really fast over the others, and sometimes it fails. So there's an issue with the original code then.. bleh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you look at the [sortable demo with placehoder](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder) and use the following code to initialize the sortable you'll see a sliding action in the placeholder

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    start: function (e,ui){        // new lines to
      $(ui.placeholder).slideUp(); // remove popping
    },                             // effect on start
    change: function (e,ui){
      $(ui.placeholder).hide().slideDown();
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

you can change the class ui-state-highlight to anything you want to style it, you can make it invisible by using css-property visibility and set it to hidden

i made the basic example in [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/ekezo3/) so you can see what its like

EDIT: [example](http://jsbin.com/ekezo3/2/) with the popping-effect removed when you *start* sorting

Comment: That's a good way to go!
Only one thing. When you hide it, all elements "below" the placeholder will jump up to where the placeholder was, then they would start to slide down. Is there a way to "lock" them or so? Because it looks very funny if you drag the 5th over the 4th element in your example...

Comment: Works great when dragging over, but when dragged away the placeholder simply vanishes giving a jump/snapped appearance.  Is there a way to also detect the dragging away?

Comment: the placeholder gets removed by jquery so it will get a little bit more complicated. I'd say you have to insert your own placeholder element on the change event and animate it yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to slide with:

```
(...).sortable({
revert : 300, ...
```

The number is in milliseconds for the animation.
Also see similar post: [In JQuery Sortable, how can I run a function before the revert animation starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540614/in-jquery-sortable-how-can-i-run-a-function-before-the-revert-animation-starts)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can control it with the events options. check them out...
2. becareful with the queue because if you drag one element and then drag the other withouth the first one finishing that can look funny.
3. I would recommend you to read about .stop(), jq queue, and possibly "cancel bubble"

Comment: Ah ok, maybe its 'better' to use the events.
But what do you mean by 'controling' it? The objects are static, by other words, they cannot be moved on the page dynamically unless you change the property to fixed/absolute, and that creates a whole lot of problems..

Comment: i mean you can use `start: function (){...}` to create a ghost element and then use `drag:function (){...}` to move the ghost
finally use `stop: function (){...}` to destroy ghost and then slide the original to the end position. or something like that.