# Make jQuery sortable smoother

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, placeholder, smoothing

Im working the first time with jQuery sortable. And i tried to make the sorting a little bit smoother, but found nothing in online doku. The issue is, that jQuery sortable produces only one placeholder, which just jumps to the snappable areas. It will be much smoother, when on leaving an area, an other placeholder will be generated (hidden). So both can be animated with slideToggle.
Is there a way to realize this?

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329550/jquery-sortable-plugin-with-sliding-effect) which treats with a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

Um, not sure I can solve your problem completely but this might make it a little bit smoother:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable-thing" ).sortable({ revert: true });
});
```

That makes it (instead of snapping) smoothly glide to its position, but it doesn't do this for other items not being dragged at the time, and also I think it might be a bit glitchy cos it's designed for draggable. Hope this helps :D