# In JQuery Sortable, how can I run a function before the revert animation starts?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

An example JQuery sortable snippet:

```
 $("#sortable").sortable({ 
     start: function(){ $('#overlay').show('fast'); });
     stop: function(){ $('#overlay').hide('fast'); });
     revert: true;
 });
```

I'd like my overlay to at least *start* hiding BEFORE the revert animation begins, because it feels slow otherwise. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the revert animation is executed before the internal `_clear()` function is executed which triggers the events `beforeStop`and `stop`.

A possible workaround is to provide a number for the `revert` option instead of a boolean. From the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-revert):

> If set to true, the item will be reverted to its new DOM position with a smooth animation. Optionally, **it can also be set to a number that controls the duration of the animation in ms.**

So you can set a smaller revert animation duration, for instance 150ms, so it does not look too slow:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({ 
     start: function(){ $('#overlay').show('fast'); },
     stop: function(){ $('#overlay').hide('fast'); },
     revert: 150
});
```

In complement, you could replace the `stop` event by defining define a [one-time `mouseup` event](http://api.jquery.com/one/) on the helper when you start the dragging, in which you will start hiding your `#overlay` element. As soon as the mouse button is released, the handler will be executed along with the revert animation:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({ 
     start: function(){
         // set a one-time "mouseup" event on the helper
         $(ui.helper).one('mouseup', function() {
             // when mouse button is released, "#overlay" will start hiding
             // along with reverting animation
             $('#overlay').hide('fast');
         });
         $('#overlay').show('fast'); 
     },
     revert: 150
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/xxdRK/)**

Comment: I liked the slower revert animation, but your mouseup trick is exactly what I was looking for. Everything seems obvious once you see it :-) Thanks for your extra time in making the jfiddle for me!!

Comment: Well I came first with the revert animation, was more a trick, made me think of the actual solution when making the fiddle. Glad it helped !